# Linux Bash Shell - File globbing specific range?

Tags: linux, bash, globbing

I have a bunch of files in a folder:

spreadsheet700.xls
spreadsheet800.xls
spreadsheet850.xls
spreadsheet1005.xls
spreadsheet2400.xls

how can I use file globbing to select files that numbers end in 700 or higher, but less than 1000 and put them into a new folder?

I've tried:

cp spreadsheet*.xls but the wildcard selects all. Thanks in adance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include (and tag) the program language or shell you are using so we don't have to guess. This makes it useful for others who search similar questions.

Comment: Done - Apologies for not including that info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> cp spreadsheet{7,8,9}[0-9][0-9].xls folder

This means starting with 7 or 8 or 9 and with two more digits so therefore 7xx,8xx,9xx

Comment: Works perfectly, didn't know I could use {} with [] thanks

Comment: Also spreadsheet[789][0-9][0-9].xls works the same but I thought the curly brackets make it more evident

Comment: just a note if using quotes, the special chars need to be outside just like the * wildcard

Answer (score 18):

You could also do this:

`cp spreadsheet{700..999}.xls folder`

This is simpler and also gives you more precision on starting and ending the range (the accepted answer only works if you want to get the same sets of digits for 7xx, 8xx and 9xx).

It's called Brace Expansion:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: In the bash manpage search for "Brace Expression". --  A  sequence  expression  takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y are either integers or single characters, and incr, an optional increment, is an integer.

Comment: Thanks both, it appears to be called "Brace Expansion" and the answer has been updated to link to the documentation.